# OpenShift Cloud Computing: Advanced installation

Tags: docker, ansible, openshift-origin

I want to install OpenShift using the advanced installation - method on Centos7 (EC2). But first I need to know some issues:

URL of tutorial: https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.0/admin_guide/install/advanced_install.html#installing-ansible

First I need to configure the prerequisitions on the master and its 2 nodes (https://docs.openshift.org/latest/install_config/install/prerequisites.html). 
When that's done the advanced installation will start.

1) Do I have to install ansible on the master only and running the installer at the end or do I need to install anything on the node (except docker)?

2) Which steps do I have to follow here: https://github.com/openshift/openshift-ansible or just download the repo and following the tutorial.

3) Is there something necessary what needs to be installed or configured which is not cited?

Comment: Cloud/cluster computing != [tag:cluster-analysis] (aka clustering; a data mining technique). Also, this question should be migrated to **server-fault**.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct to start with the prerequisite steps outlined in the [origin documentation](https://docs.openshift.org/latest/install_config/install/prerequisites.html).

In particular,

- Ensure that you've completed [host preparation steps](https://docs.openshift.org/latest/install_config/install/prerequisites.html#host-preparation). These steps include packages that must be installed on every system.
- Ensure that you've configured [host access](https://docs.openshift.org/latest/install_config/install/prerequisites.html#ensuring-host-access). The ansible installer uses ssh key authentication by default so you must be able to login to each system (including the master) from the master with ssh key authentication.
- Ensure that the output of `hostname -f` outputs the correct hostname of each system.

Once you've finished with the prerequisite steps, you will move on to the [advanced installation section](https://docs.openshift.org/latest/install_config/install/advanced_install.html). Steps for installing ansible  and creating an ansible host inventory can be found here. You only need to install ansible on the master. Once you've installed ansible and created a host inventory you can [run the ansible playbook](https://docs.openshift.org/latest/install_config/install/advanced_install.html#running-the-ansible-installer) to begin the installation.

Afterwards, you can [verify the installation](https://docs.openshift.org/latest/install_config/install/advanced_install.html#verifying-the-installation) and then complete follow up items such as [configuring authentication](https://docs.openshift.org/latest/admin_guide/configuring_authentication.html), [creating a router](https://docs.openshift.org/latest/install_config/install/deploy_router.html) and [creating a docker registry](https://docs.openshift.org/latest/install_config/install/docker_registry.html).

If you encounter any problems with the advanced installer, create an issue with the [openshift-ansible](https://github.com/openshift/openshift-ansible/issues) project.